# Dramatic performance deterioration after Java 8 migration (Google App Engine)

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I migrated my App Engine application from Java 7 to Java 8 as described **[here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/migrating-to-java8)**.

The invoked endpoint in my App Engine application performs the following steps:

- Performs an HTTP request `using java.net.HttpURLConnection`
- Extracts text from the web page retrieved using `de.l3s.boilerpipe.sax.BoilerpipeSAXInput.BoilerpipeSAXInput`
- Creates a json object containing some fields realated to the web page visited using `com.google.gson.JsonObject`
- Returns the json in the response.

I notice a dramatic performance deterioration with Java 8.

Using the App Engine console chart, I notice a big difference in latency.
Using Java 7, latency is approximately 5 seconds.
Using Java 8, latency is approximately 15 seconds.

I extracted the following information from the logs by choosing two requests representing the average latency time. The first one  for requests on the Java 7 version and the second one for requests on the Java 8 version.

Java 7 version:

```
protoPayload.startTime: "2018-02-04T02:31:42.824065Z"    
protoPayload:.endTime: "2018-02-04T02:31:43.447840Z"   
latency: "0.623775s"
receiveTimestamp: "2018-02-04T02:31:43.799013964Z"  
timestamp: "2018-02-04T02:31:42.824065Z"
```

Java 8 version

```
startTime: "2018-02-01T14:52:07.695316Z" 
endTime: "2018-02-01T14:52:09.623029Z" 
latency: "1.927713s"
receiveTimestamp: "2018-02-01T14:52:09.693218406Z"  
timestamp: "2018-02-01T14:52:07.695316Z"
```

It is useful to clarify that running some tests on my local App Engine Environment (on my local machine), **I did not notice any difference** in the times of execution between Java 7 and Java 8.
So it seems to me that the problem does not come from the version of Java but perhaps from the App Engine environment where the two versions run. Is my assumption correct?

This is the latency graph on Java 7 version:
[image]

and on Java 8 version:
[image]

Does anyone have any ideas about the possible causes?

Comment: I have not been able to identify the cause yet.
I performed a test splitting traffic to 50% on java 7 and 50% on java 8 and I have attached the respective latency graphs.
The software is the same. The only difference is "<runtime>java8</runtime>" in my appengine-web.xml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

read https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/issue-requests

you must add the url-stream-handler as urlfetch in your appengine-web.xml as;

```
<appengine-web-app xmlns="http://appengine.google.com/ns/1.0">
  <!-- ... -->
  <url-stream-handler>urlfetch</url-stream-handler>
  <!-- ... -->
</appengine-web-app>
```

Comment: Thank you! With your suggestion I solved the problem. But there are 2 things that I do not understand: 1) In my code I use java.net.HttpURLConnection for HTTP (S) requests and not URL Fetch API. So why do I have to insert the tag that abilities urlfetch in my appengine-web.xml? 2) The google documentation talks about the three "Advantages to using Java standards and not URL Fetch in Java 8" but does not say anything about the disadvantage of latency.

Answer (score 0):

I have done the same migration, but I didn't notice any performance deterioration.

The thing that I did notice was that in Java 8 it's allowed to make background threads. And for some calls those thread keept on running after the actual request was already finished. This keept the request open longer that needed. Maybe you have something like this? (Should be some visible in the logs)

Comment: I added info from my logs that show the highest latency with java 8 and additional info coming from my test. It seems to me that the problem does not come from the version of java but perhaps from the environment app engine where the two versions run

Answer (score 0):

This may be due to the memory/CPU limitations of the App Engine instance class. Check out this question for more information: [Memory Error/500 Error when migrating from Java 7 to Java 8 on Google App Engine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54246413/memory-error-500-error-when-migrating-from-java-7-to-java-8-on-google-app-engine/54246414#54246414)